# python sklearn accuracy score for two different list

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have two lists

`y_test = array('B', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

and

`labs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

In sklearn, when i do `print accuracy_score(y_test,labs)`, i get error

> ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got array('B', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).

I tried to compare it using `print accuracy_score(y_test['B'],labs)` but it is showing

> TypeError: array indices must be integers

Comment: Do you mean `y_test = dict({'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})`; you can't form a numpy array that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have both `y_pred` and`labs` as same data type. i.e. either `array` or `list`. They are of mixed type.

*EDIT1*
Once we align that using `y_test = map(int,y_test)` , it should work (as below)

```
import array
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

y_test = array.array('B', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y_test = map(int,y_test)
labs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> print accuracy_score(labs, y_test)
1.0
```

Comment: So for `y_test = array('B', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, how can i get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: You can map array to `list` of `int` as `y_test = map(int, y_test)`. Pls check  answer for updates

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the array to list to make it work
This should do for you
accuracy_score(y_test.tolist(),labs)